# Taking invisible WebRTC/video photos without canvas/display

Tags: html, html5-canvas, video-streaming, webrtc, video-capture

I've read [*Taking still photos*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) from MDN describing how you can capture photos from the web cam (using a video element and `mediaDevices.getUserMedia`) to show them to the user using a canvas.

However I do *not* need (and do not want) to display the taken image to the user and thus I also do not want to use a canvas as I'd say that first drawing a canvas just to get the image data (as ImageData or DataUri) could be bad for the performance.

So is there a way to get the image data without using canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using canvas is totally fine and performs well. Just don't attach the canvas to the document and it won't be shown.  I think your concern about performance is unfounded.

The only other way to get data out of a stream would be [`MediaRecorder`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html) but it produces video at a given frame rate, not what you want, and much more involved.

There's talk of an [`imageCapture`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/) API, but it's not implemented in any browser yet, except [behind a flag](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-image/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md). It would offer a `.takePhoto()` method which would also give access to full-resolution photo cameras where available (i.e. phones).